# Ubuntu + Mono + ASP.NET ,is it possible?

Tags: ubuntu, mono

Anyone had experience using ubuntu desktop edition + mono project to run asp.net 4.0??
and what is the draw back of this platform?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use Ubuntu server edition, mono and apache with mod_mono to run ASP.NET MVC applications (both commercial and hobby stuff). So far I haven't run into an issue which will cause me to stop using this combination. There are however some areas which you should be aware of, for example:

- lack of support for Entity Framework (currently no plans to implement it in mono)
- LINQ to SQL is in beta release and you can run into some problems with more complex queries
- mono implementation of ASP.NET 4.0 may not be feature complete yet (personally I use only ASP.NET MVC 1 and 2 which is included in mono)
- it's a good habit to test your application under mono from time to time if your development environment is Windows/MS.NET based

Even with some compatibility issues between mono and MS.NET you can almost always find alternative solutions and technologies which can resolve your problems.